# Insert blank rows in excel if row above is not empty

Tags: excel, vba

If A1 is not empty (contains actual data), is there a way to if-then so that I can insert a blank row under A1.  This should apply to any cell/row as I have a spreadsheet with about 65000 rows and they want to have blanks to separate the rows that contain different identifiers.  I looked on here, right before I signed up, and I saw some things about empty cells or making cells empty depending on other cells, but that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.  Google wasn't too much help either.

thanks.

Comment: Will the blank cell always be in column A? I.e. if there's a blank in A10, do you want a new row above A10? Or if there's a blank cell in ANY column, add a row above?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
  Sub helping()
        Dim count As Long
        For count = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count To 1 Step -1
            If Information.IsEmpty(Cells(count, 1)) = False Then Rows(count + 1).Insert
        Next count
    End Sub
```